# Windows can't locate DLL files installed with conan

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, conan-2

I am trying to get startet with conan and am following this tutorial:

https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html

Everything seemed to work well, zlib was installed and the program was built succesfully, but when I try to run the compressor.exe I get the error "zlib1.dll not found". How do I fix this/what is going wrong here?

I am running on Windows 10 with Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: zlib1.dll needs to be somewhere that compressor.exe will find it, either in the same directory or a system path.

Comment: ***How do I fix this/what is going wrong here?*** You need to help your OS locate the dependent dlls at runtime. This Microsoft document describes how the OS finds dlls and how you can help it: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps)

Comment: I know that `vcpkg` has a script that copies the dependent dlls into the same folder as your executable if you use CMake for your application. Does conan do this for you? I am not sure I don't use connan.

Comment: It would be kind of cumbersome to do this for every single library I plan to install with conan. When I used vcpkg before, it found the dll files automatically. Doesn't conan set this up automatically or did I forget something in the install step? Do I have to add the conan folder to the PATH? I can't find anything regarding this problem online

Comment: Also, when I look in the conan folder, the zlib folder only has a zlib.lib static library, no dlls, so I don't even understand hy it's trying to use zlib1.dll

Comment: @drescherjm I have no idea, that's why I ask, I was hoping some conan savvy person who uses it on Windows would be able to help

Comment: I searched a little more and found out that before conan 2.0 there was an import command that you could use to copy dll files into the project directory. however, it doesn't seem to be present anymore in conan 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The zlib1.dll file is copied into the same folder as the executable, but whenever I try to run the program through Visual Studio, ***Visual Studio seems to delete the dll file before the program is executed***.

The next question would be ***why***? And how do I stop Visual Studio from doing that?

Edit: I'll just use VSCode from now on, from there everything seems to work better

Comment: ***The next question would be why?*** Your antivirus would be more likely reason for the dll deletion unless here is something conan related that deletes the dll. I have never (in 26+ years of usage) seen Visual Studio (and dev studio before it was named VS) delete a dll on its own.

Comment: @drescherjm When I run the executable through Visual Studio, the dll file disappears. WHen I run it through Visual Studio Code, or directly from the command line it doesn't. I don't know why this happens. I don't have any antivirus btw